# SQL add values based on select

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-server-2016

I have table `user_group` that looks something like this:

```
id_group | id_user
100      | 12
110      | 12
120      | 12
110      | 13
100      | 14
...
```

I want to add id_group 200, 300 and 400 to every user that have been assigned id_group 100 - select would be (`SELECT id_user FROM user_group WHERE id_group = '100'`)

Final table should look like this:

```
id_group | id_user
100      | 12
110      | 12
120      | 12
200      | 12
300      | 12
400      | 12 
110      | 13
100      | 14
200      | 14
300      | 14
...
```

Can somebody help? I can't get my head around it. Thanks :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a calendar table/union approach:

```sql
SELECT id_group, id_user
FROM user_group
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.id_group, t2.id_user
FROM
(
    SELECT 200 AS id_group UNION ALL
    SELECT 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 400
) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id_user FROM user_group WHERE id_group = 100) t2
ORDER BY id_user, id_group;
```

### Demo

If you really want to add the data, then use the following insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO user_group (id_group, id_user)
SELECT t1.id_group, t2.id_user
FROM
(
    SELECT 200 AS id_group UNION ALL
    SELECT 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 400
) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id_user FROM user_group WHERE id_group = 100) t2;
```